# Django: custom tag and tag evaluation in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I wrote a custom tag named `addattrs` that allow me add HTML attributes easily.

I uses it that way:

```
<div>
  <label>Last name</label>
  {{ form.last_name|addattrs:"class=blue-form&placeholder=Please enter your name" }}
</div>
```

It works well. But now, I'd like to add the `value` attribute to HTML:

```
<div>
  <label>Last name</label>
  <!-- last_name is availaible from the current context -->
  {{ form.last_name|addattrs:"class=blue-form&value=last_name" }}
</div>
```

The problem is `last_name`is not evaluated and wrote as is in my form. How to force last_name to be evaluated? I tried a `{% with last_name as myvariable %}` block, but the result is exactly the same.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The alecxe solution works.
However, if the value is a datetime, it does not work anymore (no python Error but no attribute at all in the HTML.) I tried this:

```
{% with "class=blue-form&value="|add:birth_date as attrs %}
    {{ form.birth_date|addattrs:attrs }}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add):

```
{% with "class=blue-form&value="|add:last_name as attrs %}
    {{ form.last_name|addattrs:attrs }}
{% endwith %}
```

---

For the date value, you need to convert it to a string first. Either in the view, or in the template via [`date` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date), example:

```
{% with birth_date|date:"D d M Y" as my_date %}
    {% with "class=blue-form&value="|add:my_date as attrs %}
        {{ form.last_name|addattrs:attrs }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I edited the question because a particular case does not work as you can see. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: Ohhh, nested with! Clever! Thanks again, double accepted answer :)